# Is there an R version of Python's pop() function?

Tags: r, stack

I am translating some python code and was wondering if Python's pop() function can be translated in R. Thanks!

Comment: Some explanation and example of how you'd like the code to look would be useful here.

Comment: Perhaps show a portion of the code you're converting and what R data structures you're trying to map the original problem to?

Comment: There is a [blog post](http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2013/11/implementing-a-queue-as-a-reference-class/) where a Queue class is implemented as reference class. Three different approaches (one that manipulates a global variable, a Scheme-like approach and a objected approach) are shown at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Queue/Definition#R).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a custom function to mimic Python pop function but I just want to add that this approach is not in line with the way I think R should do achieve the same task (I don't like to play with the global environment).

This example is based on the official python documentation : http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

```
pop <- function(list, i = length(list)) {
    stopifnot(inherits(list, "list"))
    res <- list[[i]]
    assign(deparse(substitute(list)), list[-i], envir = .GlobalEnv)
    res
}

stack <- list(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
pop(stack)
## [1] 7

stack
## [[1]]
## [1] 3

## [[2]]
## [1] 4

## [[3]]
## [1] 5

## [[4]]
## [1] 6

pop(stack)
## [1] 6


stack
## [[1]]
## [1] 3

## [[2]]
## [1] 4

## [[3]]
## [1] 5
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you have `v <- list("a", "b", "c")`. No matter how many times you call pop(v) it always returns "c"

Comment: @Denis I wrote this function to mimic Python pop and I tried with your vector and it works for me. Can you look at this example again  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks